# dialogCornerRadius, fontVariationSettings, ttcIndex... not found after installing and linking dependency to my app

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, build.gradle, onesignal

## Context

This problems covers android and react-native projects (including Expo ejected ones).

I was working with a recently ejected Expo (React Native) project. I had just installed **OneSignal** node package to my project.

```
npm install react-native-onesignal && react-native link react-native-onsignal
```

Then on my Android project, inside the `android/app/build.gradle` file (where the sdkNumbers, and dependencies and libs are) I had the following setting:

```
  android {
  compileSdkVersion 28
  buildToolsVersion '28.0.0'

  defaultConfig {
    ...
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
    ...
  }
```

...and in the same file, in the dependencies section I had my recently linked lib (onesignal)...

```
dependencies {
  compile project(':react-native-onesignal')
  ...    
}
```

So, my native Android project is set to be built using the API 28 features (basically that's what all the sdkNumbers set to 28 mean).

## Problem

- dialogCornerRadius not found.
- fontVariationSettings not found.
- ttcIndex not found.

**The error** I am getting when I try to build my Android app is:

```
    > Task :react-native-onesignal:verifyReleaseResources FAILED

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':react-native-onesignal:verifyReleaseResources'.
    > java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed
      Output:  /node_modules/react-native-onesignal/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/values-v28/values-v28.xml:7: 
error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
      /node_modules/react-native-onesignal/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/values-v28/values-v28.xml:11: 
error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
      /node_modules/react-native-onesignal/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/values/values.xml:970: 
error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
      /node_modules/react-native-onesignal/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/values/values.xml:971: 
error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
      error: failed linking references.
```

## Trials

I tried to change all my `com.android.support` libraries to the latest version (28) as well. The problem remained.

I tried to undo the AndroidX migration. The problem changed to some Proguard crazy stuff. Too insane, I came back to AndroidX.

Comment: post all dependency you have used.

Comment: Hello @AbhayKoradiya, the most important dependency is OneSignal as we can see from the error log... /node_modules/react-native-onesignal

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

I just had to update my dependency (onesignal) `build.gradle` file which was located in the path `node_modules/react-native-onesignal/android/build.gradle`.

Basically I changed the **onesignal**'s `compileSdkVersion` from 26

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion safeExtGet('compileSdkVersion', 26)
    buildToolsVersion safeExtGet('buildToolsVersion', '26.0.2')
```

to 28

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion safeExtGet('buildToolsVersion', '26.0.2')
```

It builds fine and notification works now.

## TL; DR

I changed the onesignal's `build.gradle` `compileSdkVersion` to same as the main Android `build.gradle` file.